# delete() versus unlink() to delete file in PHP

Tags: php

The title says it all. What would be the most performance-friendly way to delete a file? Using PHP's `unlink()`-function, or PHP's `delete()`-function?

Comment: Have you opened the corresponding manual page: http://php.net/delete ?

Comment: no, i looked at http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_delete.asp

Comment: what is w3schools.com? Why do you consult it instead of the **official** documentation?

Comment: I didn''t think of look at the documentation. I thought w3school was reliable enought. Obviously not. Sorry

Comment: Wow! That "function" is going to be my go-to example whenever I want to explain why w3schools should not be trusted!

Comment: (The difference is that one works and one doesn't: I think the title edits make this post [still] relevant, even if not the "original" intent)

Comment: @deceze Just to be fair, most documentations will contain errors or uncomplete information, even the official PHP documentation. I think it is more the *closed* nature of the w3schools which makes it hard till impossible to enhance the documentation (or even leave a comment there)..

Comment: -1 *w3schools says it is* I mean, I saw the `php` tag and set my standards to low. But, come on now, really?

Comment: @ahmed, you have edited your original question so much it's no longer even a question, just a statement saying that w3schools is useless, which few people here need to be told :-) Reverting to an actual _question._

Comment: @paxdiablo, the title edit wasn't my idea :P i simply edited the content to fit the question title, which as you say isn't even a question.

Comment: @hek2mgl But outright documenting a function that doesn't even exist...‽ What is this I don't even... ;)

Comment: @deceze Yeah kindly speaking it's not something they can be proud of. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `delete` function to delete files. As the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.delete.php) states:

> This is a dummy manual entry to satisfy those people who are looking for unlink() or unset() in the wrong place.

The links on that page will lead you to the correct function for deleting a variable ([unset](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)) or deleting a file ([unlink](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)).